# How to setup app.UseExceptionHandler with "razor page" Error.cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

I have tried to replace default MVC error page Error.cshtml with my own created Error2.cshtml **razor page**, but this doesn't work: **error 404**.

What I should additionally configure in routing to get it working?

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error2"); // new razor page is located in standard /Views/Shared folder
```

**Error2Model**

```
namespace MyApp.Views.Shared
{
    public class Error2Model : PageModel
    {
        public IActionResult OnGet() // this looks  unreliable but what to use instead?
        {
           //...
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error2");` it should work as it is in the shared folder. The `OnGet` can call `return Page();` after what ever functionality it needs to invoke

Comment: thank you! unfortunately this advice doesn't help me

Comment: Have you reviewed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.1#page-route-action-conventions

Comment: I also tried to move it to parent Views folder - doesn't help.

Comment: I am curious though, why you have it in views folder and not pages? Is it not a razor pages app?

Comment: Documentation quotes `In a Razor Pages app, the dotnet new Razor Pages template provides an Error page and an error PageModel class in the Pages folder.`

Comment: just because I'm replacing the standard error.cshtml... actually I'm not binded to it.
I will try to create Pages (till now i have them only in areas)

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you referring to the standard Core MVC or a Razor Pages app?

Comment: I do not distinct them :) this for me is a magic. but wait I've found an error in cshtml that was not shown on compilation in VS (not first time).

Comment: They are distinct as one uses controllers, while the other uses page models. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I do not understand this. In asp app there could be controllers and page models together - it is a fact. So how to distinct app? My app was created as MVC and now I "replacing" them with Razor Pages. Only HomeController left with Index and Error

Comment: Ok.Thank you, it works in /Pages/Error2.cshtml  (and doesn't work in Views, Views/Shared, Views/Home). Now it is important to check that this doesn't ruin whole app routing, since I remember there were a problems when Areas and Page exists together... to be continued...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reference [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core: Configure a custom exception handling page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configure-a-custom-exception-handling-page)

> Configure an exception handler page to use when the app isn't running in the Development environment:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    env.EnvironmentName = EnvironmentName.Production;

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
    }
```

> In a Razor Pages app, the `dotnet new` Razor Pages template provides an `Error` page and an error `PageModel` class in the `Pages` folder.

In your case you would set it to

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/error2");
```

which should be placed in the *`Pages/Error2.cshtml`*

Update its `PageModel`

```
namespace MyApp.Pages {
    public class Error2Model : PageModel {
        public IActionResult OnGet() {
           //...
            return Page();
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: thank you, may be you can help me with its continuation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711158/how-to-replace-mvc-homecontroller-index-redirects-with-razorpages-routings ?