# How to replace MVC HomeController/Index redirects with RazorPages routings?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

I'm migrating from ASP MVC Classic to ASP Razor Pages.

Only one controller left to "migrate": HomeController

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
        UserManager<WebUser> _userManager;

        public HomeController(UserManager<WebUser> _userManager)
        {
            this._userManager = _userManager;
        }

        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Account/Login", new { area = "WebUserIdentity" });
            }
            return RedirectToPage("/Index", new { area = "Downloads" });
        }
 }
```

There is no corresponded view to this controller/action.

And because of this I'm in stuck: how to configure routing for razor pages to use those redirects (to two different areas) without creating "fake" Index page?

Comment: so why not leave the controller as is and have it redirect like it does currently?

Comment: I believe you can still create a Page model for index page `Pages/IndexModel`  and do the same redirects.

Comment: just for purification. I will be happy when will be possible to delete Controller and VIews folder. ASP MVC is evil (when there is Razor Pages)

Comment: You are right. I will expirement with this. But I hope that should be possible to migrate only using pure "routing" configuration. It is strange create WHOLE PAGE :) for such common task as redirect default "/" to area. (actually the check if it is not authenticated go to another area is optional)

Comment: What is the issue with your current code? Do you have `IndexModel` under `Pages`? If you access `WebUserIdentity/Account/Login` and `Downloads/Index` from web browser, will it be able to access?

Comment: No I do not have IndexModel under Pages and I do not want to create fake "indexmodel" how it was done for MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can convert the controller to create a Page model for index page `Pages/IndexModel` and do the same redirects.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel {
    UserManager<WebUser> _userManager;

    public IndexModel(UserManager<WebUser> _userManager) {
        this._userManager = _userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync() {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null) {
            return RedirectToPage("/Account/Login", new { area = "WebUserIdentity" });
        }
        return RedirectToPage("/Index", new { area = "Downloads" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For redirecting to different pages, I suggest you try `middleware`.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            // Do work that doesn't write to the Response.
            if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && context.Request.Path != "/WebUserIdentity/Account/Login")
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/WebUserIdentity/Account/Login");
            }
            else if (context.Request.Path == "/")
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Downloads/Index");
            }
            await next.Invoke();
            // Do logging or other work that doesn't write to the Response.
        });

        app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: Thank you, Tao. This should be the correct way if you know all details, but for me it is hard to evaluate the impact on performance (this code will be executed each request) and the exception situation: should I `try.. catch` (exception there have no chance to achieve Error.cshtml ) ?